# Reason for Lowercase usernames

Tags: sanitization

I can see `validate_user()` calls `sanitize_user()` with strict argument as true, which means uppercase letters are not allowed too.

In source code, I found this comment

```
// If strict, reduce to ASCII for max portability.
    if ( $strict )
        $username = preg_replace( '|[^a-z0-9 _.\-@]|i', '', $username );
```

I would like to know how does this affect portability?

Comment: The `i` modifier in the regex pattern makes it case-insensitive, just something to note.

Comment: so what does this regex actually do here?

Comment: Replaces anything not a-z(upper or lower), 0-9(ie. any number), an underscore, period, hyphen or an @ symbol..

Comment: so how does it block the uppercase alphabets then? :S

Comment: It doesn't block uppercase characters.

Comment: what I meant was how the function blocks uppercase and not the snippet portion here

Comment: @Ashfame: actually, the function doesn't block uppercase letters. In the comment above the functions, WP writes: "If $strict is true, only **alphanumeric characters** (as well as _, space, ., -, * @) are returned.". That means uppercase letter are accepted. In fact, I have a WP where I have the username with uppercase letter, and no problems at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uppercase characters are not blocked in usernames on single site setups.

Uppercase characters ARE blocked in usernames on multisite setups. The wpmu_validate_user_signup function forces lowercase a-z and numbers 0-9 only.

Answer (score 2):

If You are not allowing users to register site, you may disable 'uppercase' restriction from MS install, just add into your theme functions.php file:

```
remove_action( 'sanitize_user', 'strtolower' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Off hand, I suppose it would be so you can use validate_user's results in a URL or a $_GET string. I'm sure there are plenty of other reasons as well, I guess I don't know what they mean by max portability...

Comment: yes, I am interested in knowing about how this affects portability. anything else like a variable from URL can be configured to converted to lowercase and then made it work. A bit extra work, but will work.